# I'm looking for proof that `create-react-app` doesn't run the `import/no-unused-modules` rule when auto-refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

I have an app created with `create-react-app`. I have extended the eslint functionality with an `eslintrc.json` file with the following rules:

```
"rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
    "react/require-default-props": "off",
    "no-param-reassign": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/alt-text": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "react/display-name": "off",
    "import/no-unused-modules": [2, {"unusedExports": true}],
    "unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "error"
  },
```

I have noticed that rules such as `unused-imports/no-unused-imports` will be used on every autorefresh, and notify me if something is wrong. However, `import/no-unused-modules` won't run when `create-react-app` autorefreshes.

When I run `npx eslint .` manually in the root directory, both of these rules are run fine and will pick up errors.

Theoretically, this seems sensible. My thinking is that `create-react-app` only checks files and modules which are imported into the build. Since `import/no-unused-modules` checks for files/modules which AREN'T imported by definition, this won't be used by `create-react-app`.

What I'm looking for is proof (e.g. code in the `create-react-app` codebase) that this is the case. How does `create-react-app` know not to run the `import/no-unused-modules` rule? I have looked online and can't find an answer to this...

Thanks!